# Is there a way to execute a PDF field script while filling its form with pdftk?

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, pdftk, php-pdftk

I've been tasked to fill a pre-made PDF form via a Symfony app. I'm using [this](https://packagist.org/packages/mikehaertl/php-pdftk) pdftk wrapper to do the job, but there's an issue.

This PDF uses some scripts for hiding/showing some field: for example, they trigger when a radio button has been selected.
When i fill the form with pdftk, the radio fields are changed correctly, but those scripts aren't executed, since those fields haven't been interacted by a human, i'm guessing.

I've already tried the flatten and need_appearances options to try to force their execution, but with no avail.

Is there a way to trigger these events from pdftk, or showing/hiding manually those fields, or there's an alternative to pdftk that does the trick? Keep in mind, i can't edit in any way the PDF, since it's an official document (in case you need it, [this](https://www.garanteprivacy.it/documents/10160/0/Modello+notifica+Data+Breach.pdf/6d1fa433-88dc-2711-22ab-dd5d476abe74?version=1.2) is the PDF)

Thank you!

Comment: Pdftk will not run any scripts, but it might be possible to do it manually. Which field attributes do the scripts modify?

Comment: Also, what happens when you open the form with a viewer that does not support JavaScript? If it works in that case, a solution might be to strip all JavaScript away from your PDF before/after filling it.